# Telegram webhook is not responding fast

Tags: telegram

My bot is in more than 50K groups and receives every message using Webhook.

Problem is, in busy hours, telegram sends updates to my webhook with a long delay (i.e. after one hour!).

Is there any reference talking about the limits and how many messages does telegram pass to webhook per second and generally how can I speed it up?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max_connections` parameter in `setWebhook`.

> Maximum allowed number of simultaneous HTTPS connections to the webhook for update delivery, 1-100. Defaults to 40.
>
> Use lower values to limit the load on your bot‘s server, and higher values to increase your bot’s throughput.